# how can I better secure from unwanted entry, some odd windows?

Tags: windows, security

I have some odd windows at the house that are not common slide up double hung windows. See diagram below 'awning' and 'hoppers'. They are about 2 foot square made of wood with plexiglass.  I know I need to replace the plexiglass.

**Windows are functionally weak and the plexiglass can be trivially pushed in.**

If I put glass in, that would definitely help, but I'm looking for an 'add-on' that I can do rather quickly.

One slides into the house wall as if it were a double hung, without the top section.  That too has plexiglass in it.  It is likely these were made custom on-site when the house was built.

The screen is a separate wood frame but is missing on these windows.

Options include:

1. Bars on inside - possibly iron pipe secured to frame.  I never use these windows.
2. Rebuild frame for screens (moderately difficult and time is a factor here)

- frame for screens could be blocked smaller than a person - I have done this already for a vertical window just enough to allow me to put a dual fan unit in it.  Ugly but functional.

3. Decorative sheet aluminum grating on outside (not as secure, but fast enough)

- Could also put proper screen material under it.

4. Build the 'screen frame' and put glass in it - but how ?

Reject the special 'security screens' as probably too costly and not available locally.
Ugly is not a factor, speed and reasonable security is.

[image: window styles]

Any other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Question is unclear.  You say "security" but talk about screens.  You want to keep bugs out?  Keep burglars out when the windows are open?  When they are closed?   Keep small children from falling out?

Comment: "Prevent the window itself from falling out of the wall" was my first thought about the word "secure". Please feel free to [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Jay613, these screens are made of 2x2 square wood with metal screen material.  Right now, there is direct access to the glass (or plexi), because there is no screen frame.  I am considering trying to build one of the small screen frames this weekend.  Its minimal improvement, but it is improvement.  If i want to, then i can make the available area in the screen smaller than a person with 1x2x4 boards.  These 'frames' attach to the house with eye hooks from the inside only.

Comment: You have way two many types listed the ones you don’t use a simple sheet metal screw can prevent the window from being opened. Some plastic sheeting like polycarbonate is more secure than glass so take that part out of the question, provide a photo of the window and ask how to temporarily secure the window so it can not be opened, or opened any further. Do this for each window type and you will get some specific answers.

Comment: Ed Beal, as always, thank you for the answers.  I can secure the windows themselves, one of the 'hoppers' style windows is secured just that way with a screw, but the glass is plexiglass and could be trivially pushed in.  Very tempted to make the 'screen frame' and can put glass in that - but how? This would sort of give me a double pane effect as well.

Comment: replace plexi with lexan; it can stop shotgun blasts. I don't like bars as that can be a death trap in a fire.